# How to Prevent a user going back to home screen after logging out

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-navigation

I am now having issues where after I log out the user is allowed to press back which takes them back to the home screen as shown here OR the user is able to go back to the login screen without logging out:
[image]

**EDIT:**
What I was trying to do is see if the user exists and if he does take him to the home screen but if not send him to the login page and signup page. This code is from my App.js. Here is the code to my navigator:

```
return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {user ? (
          <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home"
          options={{
            headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#060320',},
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold',}
          }} >
            {props => <Loans {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen 
            name="Login" 
            options={{
              headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#060320',},
              headerTintColor: 'white',
              headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold',}
            }}
            component={Login} 
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="Signup" 
            options={{
              headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#060320',},
              headerTintColor: 'white',
              headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold',}
            }}
            component={Signup} />  
          </>
          ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen 
            name="Login" 
            options={{
              headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#060320',},
              headerTintColor: 'white',
              headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold',}
            }}
            component={Login} 
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="Signup" 
            options={{
              headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#060320',},
              headerTintColor: 'white',
              headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold',}
            }}
            component={Signup} />  
          </>
          
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please show some relevant code so we can see how you've structured your navigation.

Comment: @AlvinAbia I did that right now, i forgot to do that when I made this

Comment: Sweet thank you, just posted answer

Answer (score 2):

If you're calling navigation.navigate("Login") from your Home screen, then yeah if the user hits back, it'll take them back there as that's expected behavior. This also applies for the vice versa of navigating to Home via `navigate` from your Login screen.

What you ca do is something like this:

```
<NavigationContainer>
    {user ? (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    ) : (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" />
            <Stack.Screen name="Signup" />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
</NavigationContainer>
```

This way all you need to do when a user logs in or out, you just need to set the value of `user` accordingly and only the expected screens will be available.

Comment: thank you for the help. Now I'm having trouble logging out from the home screen. It tells me that the 'Login' page was never handled by the navigator. Do you have any tips on what I can do? Because if i add it to the second Stack navigator it will allow me to go back from the home screen to the login page.

Comment: You're not supposed to call `navigate('Login')` manually as it says in the auth flow docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow#how-it-will-work

Comment: just a note - the problem is indeed declaring the screens in both branches of the condition, but "your problem is that you're using only one StackNavigator" is not correct, even in your code, both `<Stack.Navigator>` refer to the same component from React's point of view, so no need to write it twice.